# Adding script causes issue with navigation

Tags: angular, ziggeo-api

For an Angular project we would like to use embedded Ziggeo videos.
In the `index.html` header I have added the necessary Ziggeo scripts as stated on their site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://assets.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.css" />
<script src="https://assets.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.js"></script>
<script>
var ziggeoApp = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
    token:"APPLICATION_TOKEN"
});
</script>
```

(https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-integration/header)

This seems to work fine, I can see and play the videos. However, this causes the navigation of the site to malfunction. Every menu-item needs two clicks to navigate, and buttons with navigation stopped working entirely (they use `router.navigate`). I see the URL changing, but no navigation takes place. In the console, I see the error `Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?`.
I cannot find anything regarding this error and adding scripts. I have disabled various other scripts in case they interfere with one another, but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the steps here: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/integrations/angular

I know it is best not to make a reply of go there, however as I am part of Ziggeo team, I know that our goal is to always do our best to keep the resource available and updated. So I will copy the codes from the above page, however still suggest checking it for more details.

Alternatively you can also visit Github to check [out the demo](https://github.com/Ziggeo/angular2-ziggeo-demo/tree/master).

Grab the Ziggeo's Angular SDK from here: https://github.com/Ziggeo/angular-ziggeo and do `npm install` in your project folder.

If you are making UMD app you can just use `import {ZiggeoModule} from 'angular-ziggeo'` in your file to include Ziggeo.

That should be it, of course you should also remove the code you have added manually :)

The link I mentioned above would offer you a bit more details of course, really want to avoid copy pasting the page :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does the npm package also work with the ziggeoplayer-tag instead of the component ziggeo-player? We receive a pile of text from an external resource with possibly a ziggeoplayer-tag in it, and we would like not to make changes in it. I thought that the scripts were necessary for ziggeoplayer and the npm package for the ziggeo-player-component.

Comment: I managed to get it working with the ziggeo-client-sdk and the scripts in the angular.json :)